# Is ++*ptr++ undefined behaviour in c++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have been asked the following question in a test (I didn't want to write it myself. The test asked it. I know its bad code still) about evaluating ++*ptr++

```
int Ar[ ] = { 6 , 3 , 8 , 10 , 4 , 6 , 7} ;
int *Ptr = Ar  ;
cout<<++*Ptr++  ;
```

However, I suspect this is undefined behavior since it can be both `(++*ptr)++` or `++(*ptr++)`. 
Is it? I am not too well acquainted with documentation so I couldn't find anything.

Comment: What did C++ do to you that you feel compelled to do this?

Comment: No it is well-formed.

Comment: When asking about "undefined behaviour" the best approach is to look in the documentation first.

Comment: Independently from its well-formedness, why would you ever write such code?

Comment: @soham: Generally speaking, asking about complex interactions of multiple `++` instances and such, which represents code that should *never be written*, will attract downvotes. Or to put it another way, if you have to ask if it's well-defined, don't write it that way.

Comment: @tadman Sorry but I didn't understand your point

Comment: @soham Why do you think it's undefined? I think you'd get less downvotes if you explained that in the question.

Comment: Combining pre and postfix increment operators is cruel to anyone trying to read this code and make sense of your intent. If you suspect this is undefined behaviour the first step is to look at the C++ specification or a good reference book on the subject of pre and post increment operators and how they can work with a de-referencing pointer operation.

Comment: @MatteoItalia This was asked in a test, sir ... I didn't want to write it myself

Comment: If you really want to do this, probably try rewriting it as `++(*(ptr++))`. Easier to understand.

Comment: @soham Generally, ugly expressions like this one cause UB if/when they change a variable more than once in one place. Since this one doesn't (one `++` changes the pointer, another `++` changes a pointed `int`), it's well-defined.

Comment: @tadman actually if you suspect it is undefined the first and only step is to rewrite expression eliminating the doubt.

Comment: @soham correct answer to that test "person, who wrote this should be fired"

Comment: You should have tagged the question as language lawyer. Than comments like 'why did you do it' would not be applicable, and the question would have been taken on it's merit.

Comment: Fired might be excessive, but they certainly get the stink-eye during the code review and head off to rewrite before a second code review. If they flunk that review for the same reasons...

Comment: That's easy; it's the same as `cout<<(*Ptr+++=1);` ;-)

Comment: I think this is actually a good _test question_, because what it's testing is whether you understand that `++*ptr` does something different than `*++ptr`, and formulating it in this way forces the test-taker to engage their brain rather than regurgitating a memorized fact.

Comment: This code has a well-defined behaviour of the developer being slapped hard on their head by whoever needs to support this.

Comment: @zwol: OTOH, it's a bad question for anyone who (like me) uses parens to force evaluation order, rather than depending on my memory of precedence rules.  I've got only so many brain cells, you know, and have better things to do with them :-)

Comment: could also be written as `++Ptr++[0]`

Comment: And this is, why every C/C++ programmer should have their operator precedence table under their keyboard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)...

Comment: I'd prefer `++(++Ptr)[-1]` or even `++-1[++Ptr]`, because pre-increment is always better than post-increment (this comment may contain sarcasm).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

> However I suspect this is undefined behaviour since it can be both `(++*ptr)++` or `++(*ptr++)`. Is it?

Not really, unlike the runtime behavior, which gives ample leeway to implementors, in C++ parsing itself follows quite strict and well-defined rules<sup>1</sup>. Indeed, looking at the [precedence rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `++*Ptr++` is actually parsed as `++(*(Ptr++))`.

This trick question instead is probably alluding to the undefined behavior of expressions such as [`i = ++i + ++i`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/340282/214671), where you have a value that appears multiple times in an expression, and is subjected to a modification by a side-effect of the expression itself. Such expressions are illegal, as, unless there's some operator that sequences the side effects<sup>2</sup>, the exact moment in which they are applied is not defined, so it's undefined exactly what values `i` would assume in the various points of the expression.

Still, there's no undefined behavior here, as all side effects in the expression operate on different values, which appear only once in the expression: the "inner" `++` affects `Ptr`, while the outer one affects the value pointed originally by `Ptr`, i.e. `Ar[0]`.

```
++(*(Ptr++))
     ^^^^^____increments Ptr, returning its original value
   ^^^^^^^^______dereferences the original Ptr, AKA &Ar[0]
^^^^^^^^^^^^_______ increments Ar[0]
```

That being said, if I ever saw such an expression in a code base of ours I'd go to great lengths to find the author and make sure that this wouldn't happen again.

---

1. If sometimes very bizarre and absurdly costly to implement. Still, there *are* instances of undefined behavior in the standard describing some corner cases of the parsing, but it's orders of magnitude less pervasive than "runtime" undefined behavior.
2. A handy summary of those rules [can be found here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules); interestingly, some extra guarantees have been added in C++17.

Comment: @val what made it legal?

Comment: The behavior of `i = ++i + ++i` is undefined in C++17

Comment: @val: just checked again: it's not legal. C++17 just added a sequence point for assignment and compound assignment operators. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46171943/214671 `++i + ++i` remains illegal even just by itself (without assignment on the left).

Comment: @MatteoItalia more formally [intro.execution](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#10) the operands of addition operator are unsequenced

Comment: Also, [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules); from point 14 are the modifications introduced in C++17; they are quite something (and significantly more than what the answer I linked above), but they don't include addition.

Comment: What if `*Ptr` references `Ptr` itself, would that make it undefined behaviour?

Comment: Re: "Such expressions [as `i = ++i + ++i`] are illegal, as, unless there's some operator that sequences the side effects, the exact moment in which they are applied is not defined, so it's undefined exactly what values `i` would assume in the various points of the expression": I'm not sure I agree with this explanation. That explanation would explain why the behavior of `i = ++i + ++i` was *unspecified*, if it were; but the behavior is completely *undefined*, and that explanation doesn't really explain why.

Comment: @ruakh It's undefined because it cannot be defined.  It carries too much ambiguity.  The question "Why is it undefined" is because you can't define it.

Comment: @ruakh: ultimately, it's undefined because the standard says it's undefined; a good rationalization is that the standard left so much leeway for implementors to apply side-effects whenever and however they feel best that they went all the way and left it completely undefined to allow for any possible optimization (say, store half a value at some moment and the other half later, generating a trap representation in the meantime).

Answer (score 23):

This

```
++*Ptr++;
```

doesn't cause U.B and is evaluated as `++(*(Ptr++))`

- `ptr++;`  `/* address post incremented i.e doesn't change here itself */`
- `*ptr;`   `/* dereference same address i.e value at location where ptr earlier pointed i.e 6 */`
- `++*ptr;` `/* value changed where ptr pointed i.e Ar[0] becomes 7 */`

Note that post increments `Ptr++` evaluated as

- `Ptr;` `/* Ptr doesn't change here itself in same expression */`
- `Ptr = Ptr + 1;` `/* in next expression, Ptr considers the incremented one */`