# Unexpected behaviour with cout and incrementing

Tags: c++, cout

Lets say I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    int i = 3;
    std::cout << ++i << " " << i++;
}
```

Since the first increment is done before, and the second one after, I expected that code to output this:

`4 4`

And if not, I would have expected it to at least output this:

`5 5`

But instead what I get is:

`5 3`

which makes no sense what so ever. What is going on? I compiled it with
`g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i = ++i + ++i; in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340282/i-i-i-in-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of evaluation of arguments using std::cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718508/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-using-stdcout)

Comment: All the linked dupes are good. So, in the end you should get 4, 4 when compiling with -std=c++17 and undefined behaviour with earlier standards.

Comment: Thank you, the linked pages answered the question, I just couldn't find them earlier. So it is undefined behaviour as I suspected. My compiler doesn't seem to support c++17 so I cannot test if the behaviour is different in that standard.